# Public CLSI servers

Tags: latex

Does anyone know any publicly accessible [CLSI (Common LaTeX Service Interface)](http://code.google.com/p/common-latex-service-interface/) servers other than [ScribTeX](http://clsi.scribtex.com/)? (nothing wrong with ScribTeX, in fact it's great, but I was wondering if there are any alternatives)

EDIT: I'm not looking for online LaTeX equation editors or proprietary APIs (e.g. [MonkeyTex](http://monkeytex.bradcater.webfactional.com/api/)), I'm asking specifically about CLSI because it seems to be the standard for server-side LaTeX compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's a CLSI, but there is LaTeXLab, built on google's app engine. http://code.google.com/p/latex-lab/

Comment: yeah I saw this one, it can connect to an external CLSI instance for compilation but I couldn't find a CLSI endpoint in the project itself.

Comment: ah. alright. i really like latexlab's option to use a local tex installation. that is awesome :P

Comment: I checked with LaTeX Lab's author, there is a CLSI server but it's only usable from LaTeX Lab's frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit old question but you can use 
https://github.com/overleaf/clsi

From the overleaf project

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's a CLSI server but http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/ is very nice and can probably be scripted, eg. http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php?filename=&latextext=%5Czeta%282%29%3D%5Cpi%5E2%2F6&outtype=png&bgcolor=white&txcolor=black&res=150&antialias=1

Comment: thanks but this is only an equation editor, it can't compile fully-fledged LaTeX documents, with BibTeX, etc.