# Run makefile or latex on Google Drive

Tags: php, makefile, latex, google-drive-api

Is it possible to run e.g. a makefile or latex on files that are stored on Google Drive?

Consider the following scenario:
Google Drive App user (logged in on his own Google Drive) 'runs' a makefile or latex on a server e.g. using a php script.
It is (relatively) easy to download the makefile or latex file at the server side, and exec a specific command (e.g. 'make' or 'latex').
The problem is that the makefile or latex file needs other files that are stored locally on the user's Google Drive. However, I do not want to download all the files to the server 'just in case'.

Maybe a complete Google Drive folder can be mapped on the server for this session?
Or maybe symlinks can be made for the complete file tree, and when they are accessed, the actual file content can be downloaded on the server?

Does anybody have any ideas and practical tips how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

No turn key solution for PHP as far as I know.

If you have admin rights on the (Linux) server the PHP runs on, you can [mount Google drive in an ordinary folder](https://github.com/jcline/fuse-google-drive). If you are willing to do quite some programming, you could start out with [vfs://Stream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/) which is PHP only AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to `ssh` into your Google Drive (which I don't know) you could use the `sshfs` command to mount it and then execute whatever commands you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Latex: CLSI (common latex service interface) seems to be a viable candidate, as it accepts urls to your resources. See the following links:

- http://code.google.com/p/common-latex-service-interface/
- https://github.com/scribtex/clsi
- [Public CLSI servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322069/public-clsi-servers)

The downloadUrl of the google drive resources can then be passed in the CLSI request.
See my answer in [google drive: access webContentLink through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864657/google-drive-access-webcontentlink-through-javascript) for getting the downloadUrl in javascript.